# How show that $\det(a^{b_{i}}_{i}+1)+\det(a^{b_{i}}_{i}-1)>0$

Tags: matrices, inequality, determinant

Let $1\le a_{1}<a_{2}<\cdots<a_{n},1\le b_{1}<b_{2}<\cdots<b_{n}$, show that

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a^{b_{1}}_{1}+1&a^{b_{2}}_{1}+1&\cdots&a^{b_{n}}_{1}+1\\
a^{b_{1}}_{2}+1&a^{b_{2}}_{2}+1&\cdots&a^{b_{n}}_{2}+1\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
a^{b_{1}}_{n}+1&a^{b_{2}}_{n}+1&\cdots&a^{b_{n}}_{n}+1
\end{vmatrix}
+\begin{vmatrix}
a^{b_{1}}_{1}-1&a^{b_{2}}_{1}-1&\cdots&a^{b_{n}}_{1}-1\\
a^{b_{1}}_{2}-1&a^{b_{2}}_{2}-1&\cdots&a^{b_{n}}_{2}-1\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
a^{b_{1}}_{n}-1&a^{b_{2}}_{n}-1&\cdots&a^{b_{n}}_{n}-1
\end{vmatrix}>0.$$

This problem is two years ago problem.

Comment: Hint: $$\det(a_i^{b_j} + 1 ) + \det(a_i^{b_j} -1 ) = 2 \det(a_i^{b_j}) > 0$$
To show the last inequality, you probably need to use [generalized Vandermonde matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedVandermondeMatrix.html).